# How to scrape multiple pages with this script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I have a list of URLs, I made a loop where the goal is to look over all those links and scrape some data BUT on several pages.

Maybe it's because I mixed up Selenium and BeautiffulSoup and it's not done correctly but my script gave me csv files with wrong output.

if I tell the script to go for 2 pages, the ouptut will be csv files with data from the first pages but twice. Like that :

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Npfx.png)

As you can see, doublons instead of two pages of comments scrolled with selenium.

Here's my script :

```
import re
import json
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time
import random
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait     
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By     
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

PATH = "driver\chromedriver.exe"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1200,900")
options.add_argument('enable-logging')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=PATH)

driver.get('https://www.tripadvisor.ca/')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)

j = 2 #number of pages

for url in linksfinal: 

    driver.get(url) 

    results = requests.get(url)

    comms = []
    notes = []
    dates = []
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

    name = soup.find('h1', class_= '_1mTlpMC3').text.strip()

    commentary = soup.find_all('div', class_='_2wrUUKlw _3hFEdNs8')

    for k in range(j): #iterate over n pages

        for container in commentary:

            comm  = container.find('q', class_ = 'IRsGHoPm').text.strip()
            comms.append(comm)

            comm1 = str(container.find("div", class_="nf9vGX55").find('span'))
            rat = re.findall(r'\d+', str(comm1))
            rat1 = (str(rat))[2]
            notes.append(rat1)

            time.sleep(3) 


        next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="ui_button nav next primary "]')
          
        next.click()

    data = pd.DataFrame({
    'comms' : comms,
    'notes' : notes,
    #'dates' : dates
    })

    data.to_csv(f"{name}.csv", sep=';', index=False)

    time.sleep(3)
```

I guess It has to be something with my indentation but I don't see where ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you trying to iterate over n pages inside the `for k in range(j):` loop, but you actually still iterating over `containers` which are members of `commentary` while `commentary` is taken from `soup` that is taken from `results` that is taken from `results = requests.get(url)`.
In other words, maybe you are clicking on the next button with `next.click()` but you are still iterating on data gathered at the beginning, on the first page presented by `requests.get(url)` command.
**UPD**
I'm not sure if this will work, but I guess you should do something like this:

```
driver.get('https://www.tripadvisor.ca/')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)

j = 2 #number of pages

for url in linksfinal: 

    driver.get(url) 

    results = requests.get(url)

    comms = []
    notes = []
    dates = []
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

    name = soup.find('h1', class_= '_1mTlpMC3').text.strip()

    commentary = soup.find_all('div', class_='_2wrUUKlw _3hFEdNs8')

    for k in range(j): #iterate over n pages

        for container in commentary:

            comm  = container.find('q', class_ = 'IRsGHoPm').text.strip()
            comms.append(comm)

            comm1 = str(container.find("div", class_="nf9vGX55").find('span'))
            rat = re.findall(r'\d+', str(comm1))
            rat1 = (str(rat))[2]
            notes.append(rat1)

            time.sleep(3) 


        next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="ui_button nav next primary "]')
          
        next.click()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

        commentary = soup.find_all('div', class_='_2wrUUKlw _3hFEdNs8')

    data = pd.DataFrame({
    'comms' : comms,
    'notes' : notes,
    #'dates' : dates
    })

    data.to_csv(f"{name}.csv", sep=';', index=False)

    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Prophet, you again ? :) Thanks for the answers, do you have any ida how to fix that ?

Comment: Yes, it's me still or again. Prefer sitting here instead of Facebook :) Also not registering here each day with new username, so I don't know who were you in he previous incarnation. Anyway, yes, will try to rewrite your code and paste updated answer soon

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how to rewrite this since I can't clearly understand the site you are working on. It looks like a Facebook, but I'm not sure.  Anyway, generally you should read the page data with `soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")` after each clicking on the next page button. But your nested `for` loops structure is built differently, so I don't know.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the link ! It's tripadvisor, I edited my post

Comment: I didn't put it earlier because I skipped the first part for clarity sake

Comment: I can't find elements you are using here. Probably because I didn't register there. But I hope this will work, what I suggesting here

Comment: Do you asking me or did you try?

Comment: No no I did try but same output.

Comment: Well, if so I need to debug this to give a solution but unfortunately I don't have Selenium in Python installed on my PC...

Comment: It's quick to install if you want :)

Comment: I think one day I will do that, but still had no time for that...